# How do you prevent FtpUpload@2 from creating extra root folders on the ftp server when using Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

FtpUpload@2 is creating an extra folder on my ftp server when it uploads. It creates a folder with the name of the project instead of creating just the root file structure

e.g. instead of creating `/wwwroot/...` its creating `/projectname/wwwroot/...` on the ftp server. So when I look in the folder I see (image below) a folder with the project name, where I was expecting to see a `wwwroot` folder and some files.

[image]
[image]

[image]
So for example I end up with

```
http://domain/projectname/page.html
```

When I actually want

```
http://domain/page.html
```

The directory tree underneath is correct but I don't need/want the extra folder.

What settings can I use to stop this, please? My YAML is below

```yaml
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: True
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: false

- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload'
  inputs:
      credentialsOption: inputs
      serverUrl: 'ftp://ftp.xxxxxxx.com'
      username: 'xxxxxxxxx'
      password: 'xxxxxxxxx'
      remoteDirectory: '/'
      trustSSL: true
      cleanContents: true
      rootDirectory: $(Build.artifactstagingdirectory) 
      preservePaths: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce above issue. The FtpUpload task works fine for me. It looks like the `wwwroot` folder doesnot reside directly in the `$(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)` folder. It is most likely its path is `$(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)/projectname/wwwroot`.

Or you might mistakenly set the **physical path** for your ftp server to include the projectname folder like this `c:\site\projectname`

You can add a powershell task to `ls` your `$(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)` directory to check your `$(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)` folder structure. And change the `rootDirectory` field of FtpUpload task accordingly.

```
- powershell: |
   
   ls  $(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

I had a test on my pipeline. It worked all fine. See below:

1, Below is the folder structure of the `$(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

[image]

2, My FtpUpload task has the exactly same configuration.

```
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: '..'
    username: '..'
    password: '..'
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    remoteDirectory: /
    cleanContents: true
    preservePaths: true
```

3, See below result screenshot. No extract folder is created.

[image]

Update:

I found you used dotnet publish task to publish your app. There is a `modifyOutputPath` field for dotnet publish task. Its default value is `true` which will have the project file name prefixed to their folder names when output path is specified explicitly in arguments. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops).

You can either change the dotnet publish task to disable the modifyOutputPath field `modifyOutputPath: false`,

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: True
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: false
        modifyOutputPath: false  #add this field

- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload'
  inputs:
      ....
      cleanContents: true
      rootDirectory: $(Build.artifactstagingdirectory) 
      preservePaths: true
```

Or change the `rootDirectory` field for FTPupload task to `$(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)/projectname`

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Publish
          inputs:
            command: publish
            publishWebProjects: True
            arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
            zipAfterPublish: false
            
    
    - task: FtpUpload@2
      displayName: 'FTP Upload'
      inputs:
          ....
          cleanContents: true
          rootDirectory: $(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)/projectname 
          preservePaths: true
```

Comment: I've updated the YAML to show the publish task which is the step before. I freely admit I might have the settings wrong as I had to piece this together as the documentation isn't clear to me. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: no-way! I was looking at that parameter as well but was convinced it would not do what I wanted. thanks for your help. until the next problem lol