# Azure pipeline: trying to upload files at root of FTP instead of ./pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, ftp, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to upload project files to FTP using Azure Pipeline. It work so far, but there is still one problem that remains. When Azure uploads the fiels it put it inside `./pipeline` instead of directly in the remote directory.

Here is my YAML configuration:

```
steps:
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload: ./dist'
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: '<FTP Service>'
    rootDirectory: ./dist
    filePatterns: './**/*.*'
    remoteDirectory: .
    clean: true
    preservePaths: true
    trustSSL: true
```

I tried to run FTP command to move the files in the task, but that doesn't work at all.

Is there a way to upload directly to the remote directory without any superfluous folder?
Should I run something else afterwards?

If that might be to any use, I use 2 NPM task beforehand to deploy a Vuejs app.

EDIT / SPECIFICATION

The deployment works. The problem is that the application can not be accessed like this: `myurl.net` it has to be accessed like this `myurl.net/pipeline`.

Comment: It does not work even after trying what was mentioned here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ftp-upload-to-remote-root-folder/194981

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64810842/how-do-you-prevent-ftpupload2-from-creating-extra-root-folders-on-the-ftp-serve

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I tried the Powershell method to make sure the folder exists. It does, but it does work anyway. I'm not really an infra guy nor really proficient with Powershell, and from what I read, Powershell does not support operation on FTP? is that right? Like just moving the content from `/pipeline` to `..`